# matlab matrix indexing of multiple columns

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization

Say I have a  IxJ  matrix of values,

```
V= [1,4;2,5;3,6];
```

and a IxR matrix X of indexes,

```
X = [1 2 1 ; 1 2 2 ; 2 1 2];
```

I want to get a matrix Vx that is IxR such that for each row i, I want to read R times a (potentially) different column of V, which are given by the numbers in each corresponding column in X.

```
Vx(i,r) = V(i,X(i,r)).
```

For instance in this case it would be

```
Vx = [1,4,1;2,5,5;6,3,6];
```

Any help to do this fast, (without any looping) is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you want to achieve is using vectorization to achieve speed. This is one of the major strength of MATLAB. What you want is a matrix (`index` in the following code) whose elements are linear indexes that will be used to pick out value from the source matrix(`V` in your case).  The first two lines of codes are doing exactly the same thing as `sub2ind`, turning subscripts to linear indexes.  I'm coding this way so the logic of index conversion is clear.

```
[m,n] = ndgrid(1:size(X,1),1:size(X,2));
index = m + (X-1)*size(X,1);
Vx = V(index);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for an efficient solution -

```
N = size(V,1)
Vx = V(bsxfun(@plus,[1:N]',(X-1)*N))
```

Sample run -

```
>> V
V =
     1     4
     2     5
     3     6
>> X
X =
     1     2     1
     1     2     2
     2     1     2
>> N = size(V,1);
Vx = V(bsxfun(@plus,[1:N]',(X-1)*N))
Vx =
     1     4     1
     2     5     5
     6     3     6
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method would be to use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) combined with [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).  `sub2ind` takes in row and column locations and the output are column-major linear indices that you can use to vectorize access into a matrix.  Specifically, you want to build a 2D matrix of row indices and column indices which is the same size as `X` where the column indices are exactly specified as `X` but the row indices are the same for each row that we're concerned with.  Concretely, the first row of this matrix will be all 1s, the next row all 2s, etc.  To build this row matrix, first generate a column vector that goes from 1 up to as many rows as there are `X` and replicate this for as many columns as there are in `X`.  With this new matrix and `X`, use `sub2ind` to generate column-major linear indices to finally index `V` to produce the matrix `Vx`:

```
subs = repmat((1:size(X,1)).', [1 size(X,2)]); %'
ind = sub2ind(size(X), subs, X);
Vx = V(ind);
```